# Glide displaying thumb from video, downloads the entire video

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm maintaining an android app that uses Glide to download images.

Besides images, sometimes it also displays videos, and uses the same process to display the video thumbnail.

I noticed in this cases, Glide correctly extracts and displays a thumb, BUT it always downloads the entire video do do that, which is not convenient.

My question is: Is it possible to make Glide stop downloading after reading the first frame? Or Glide is not recommended for this job?

This is a test code.
I also tried adding .frame(30_000_000L) in the requireOptions.

```
btn.setOnClickListener{
    // a local server just for testing
    val url = "http://192.168.1.6:5676/roxo.mov" 

    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
            .override(200, 200)
            .into(img_view)
}
```

Comment: "Is it possible to make Glide stop downloading after reading the first frame?" -- note that this may or may not be possible in general depending on the video format. Under the covers, Glide appears to use `MediaMetadataRetriever`, and that may or may not work with a truncated video file. If this is your server, perhaps you could prepare thumbnails there for Glide to download, instead of relying on it figuring out a thumbnail on the fly.

Comment: So the answear is No. I changed the app to use jpg thumbs downloaded from the server. Thanks for your answear!